How to insert SharePoint person field using power apps
I have a form with mutlipe fields. I have divided the fields into different forms(the same datasource).
I'm after one submit button to submit all the records at one. But the issue is some of the fields have person fields
I tried using patch below but it doesn't insert the person field Manager record
Patch(
    'Employment Onboarding',
    Defaults('Employment Onboarding'),
    { Manager: {
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & ComboBox3.Selected.Mail,
            Department: "",
            DisplayName: ComboBox3.Selected.DisplayName,
            Email: ComboBox3.Selected.Mail,
            JobTitle: "",
            Picture: ""
        }},
    frmEmpl.Updates,
    frmJob.Updates,
    frmEquip.Updates,
    frmAttach.Updates
    
);

Any idea what I am missing and is it possible

Did you try adding Manager field in any of the available forms or in new form ONLY for manager field?

The Manager fieldis only on the frmJob form and yes its only in new form mode

If you are already using frmJob.Updates, why you have to add data to manager field separately in Patch function?

Thanks Ganesh. When i only use the frmJob.Updates the Manager field doesn't insert the record for the Manager. Please keep in mind that for the Manager field I have to use a custom combo box field and its not pat for the default form

If you are using "person or group" field in SharePoint, it should show the combo box in Form control by default and should also allow selecting users from the tenant. It should work if you don't have any custom logic for your combo box. Anyway, with frmJob, try adding below formula to Update property of your Manager field "Data card" inside the frmJob form control. Let me know if it works for you.

{             '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",             Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & ComboBox3.Selected.Mail,             Department: "",             DisplayName: ComboBox3.Selected.DisplayName,             Email: ComboBox3.Selected.Mail,             JobTitle: "",             Picture: ""         }

Ganesh I forgot to mention i'm using the modern form new control. The default person field doesn't automatically let you search for users from your tenancy.
What i did to fix it is to copy the dropdown control of a person field from a classic form and replace /use it in my modern form. After this the issue was solved and the person fields are saving.
Your solution could probably work tooo but i have to test it

ok, glad it worked for you!
